# convert row into columns in oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

how can i convert rows in to columns in  oracle 10g( like pivot in oracle 11g),so that i can add multiple 'and' conditions for the primary key.

ex: select emp_name from emp

where empid = 1 and emp_age = 21;
where empid = 12 and emp_age = 23;

without using 'in' ,i have to get records which satisfies all the above condtions(Like 'and ' operation).

Answer (score 2):

This [blog entry on pivot queries](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/search/label/pivot) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in sql. If you know how many columns you need read this:
http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/09/pivot-and-crosstab-queries.html

```
CREATE TABLE CFL (season NUMBER(4), team VARCHAR2(16), points NUMBER(3));
INSERT INTO CFL (season, team, points) VALUES (2004, 'Argonauts', 21);
INSERT INTO CFL (season, team, points) VALUES (2004, 'Alouettes', 28);
INSERT INTO CFL (season, team, points) VALUES (2004, 'Tiger-Cats', 19);
INSERT INTO CFL (season, team, points) VALUES (2004, 'Renegades', 10);
INSERT INTO CFL (season, team, points) VALUES (2003, 'Argonauts', 18);


SELECT team, 
DECODE (season, 2002, points, NULL) Yr2002,
DECODE (season, 2003, points, NULL) Yr2003,
DECODE (season, 2004, points, NULL) Yr2004
FROM (SELECT season, team, points FROM CFL);
```

Comment: decode statement is equivalent to , IF-THEN-ELSE statement:

but i need to add condtion as where season =2002 and points =10 , where season =2003 and points =26 

for the above where condtion i need to apply 'AND' operation. is there any way to get.