# Changing columns to rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to convert the result of the below query into row output.

```
select 'Purchase','Sale','Discount','Out of Stock' from dual
```

Output:

```
Purchase
Sale
Discount
Out of Stock
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle10G SQL : Turning Columns into rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643731/oracle10g-sql-turning-columns-into-rows)

Comment: `select 'Purchase' from dual union all select 'Sale' from dual union all ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UNPIVOT to get it. UNPIVOT is opposite of PIVOT and it converts column values to

```
        with tbl(col1,col2,col3,col4) as 
         (
         select 'Purchase','Sale','Discount','Out of Stock' from dual
         ),tbl2 as(
         SELECT *
        FROM   tbl UNPIVOT (dat for col in (col1,col2,col3, col4)))
        select dat from tbl2
```

If you have 1 more row, then it is better to populate the column names also like below.

```
        with tbl(col1,col2,col3,col4) as 
         (
         select 'Purchase','Sale','Discount','Out of Stock' from dual union
         select 'foo','bar','data','blah' from dual
         )
         SELECT *
        FROM   tbl UNPIVOT (dat for col in (col1,col2,col3, col4));
```

But if you just want the values, then select only 'dat' column as in first example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **UNION** to have the values as different rows. For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(item) AS
  2    ( SELECT 'Purchase' FROM dual
  3    UNION
  4    SELECT 'Sale' FROM dual
  5    UNION
  6    SELECT 'Discount' FROM dual
  7    UNION
  8    SELECT 'Out of Stock' FROM dual
  9    )
 10  SELECT item FROM DATA;

ITEM
------------
Discount
Out of Stock
Purchase
Sale

SQL>
```

Remember, union doesn't allow **duplicates**, so use **UNION ALL** if you want to allow duplicate rows.