# How to pass all in between dates from date range in "IN" operator for Oracle Pivot?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I want is to pass a complete range of dates in the Pivot "IN" clause. But what i am doing is that using the values only that i am getting from database.

For ex.

Suppose if user select the From date as '10/10/2015' and To date as '10/15/2015' then I want to use all the values (10/10/2015,10/11/2015,10/12/2015,10/13/2015,10/14/2015,10/15/2015)

But what is happening from my query is ('10/10/2015','10/15'2015').

```
SELECT * FROM 
             (
 SELECT 
  Employee.M_NAME AS MANAGER_NAME,
  Employee.PHONE,
  Employee.JOB_ID,
  Employee.Assigned_DATE,
  Employee.SHIFT,
  Employee.Dept as Assignment, 
  Employee.E_ID, 
  Employee.NAME AS EMP_NAME,
  Employee.DEPT_COLOR

  FROM  Employee

  WHERE Assigned_Date BETWEEN
  TO_DATE('FD_Selected','MM/DD/YYYY') AND

  TO_DATE('TD_Selected','MM/DD/YYYY')

  ORDER by Employee.E_ID
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 min(Assignment)
                 FOR Assigned_Date IN (TO_DATE('FD_Selected','YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                      TO_DATE('TD_Selected','YYYY-MM-DD')
              )
          ) p
```

Now the data is coming like this:

```
M_NAME PHONE JOB_ID Assigned_DATE SHIFT Assignment E_ID EMP_NAME DEPT_COLOR '10/10/2015' '10/15/2015'
```

But I want like this:

```
  M_NAME PHONE JOB_ID Assigned_DATE SHIFT Assignment E_ID EMP_NAME DEPT_COLOR '10/10/2015' '10/11/2015' '10/12/2015' '10/13/2015' '10/14/2015' '10/15/2015'
```

Comment: You are using and `IN` condition. My guess is you'd need ALL the dates you want in that `IN` condition. Just try and hard code `TO_DATE('10-11-2015','YYYY-MM-DD')` in it and see if that third date is considered. If yes, I'd suggest you use another logic to get the other dates....

Comment: No Jason it doesn't, have tried already. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you would not get if hard coded. As you know, PIVOT will only return results for individual elements of the IN clause. The other dates won't be considered unless they are **explicitly** specified in the IN. For what I understand you are getting exactly what you've programmed (lol but not what you expect...)...Read this to have further information http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506

Comment: Does `TO_DATE('FD_Selected','MM/DD/YYYY')` and `TO_DATE('TD_Selected','MM/DD/YYYY')` work?

Comment: @GurV nice observation on format mask. Though even if it correct something, OP wants a result that he/she is not coding for. Two parameters in the IN conditions will only give 2 columns not more than that. OP's expectations can't be fulfilled with PIVOT clause

Comment: Thank you. But question is what can be done. I am doing Pivot but if "expectations can't be fulfilled with PIVOT clause" then what can be done @Jason in order to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Comment: It can't be done. It is not that difficult to generate all the dates between two dates. The problem is that what you put in the IN (... ) clause in PIVOT becomes some of the columns in the result set. Oracle can't even compile your query if it doesn't know, BEFORE looking at the data and processing it, how many columns will be in the result. The only way to do what you want is called "dynamic SQL". In the vast majority of cases, needing dynamic SQL is a sign that you are thinking about doing something you simply shouldn't do. If this is for reporting, use your reporting application for this.

Comment: Yes I am using this to generate a Excel report , but in that also how can it be done.

Comment: @Rambo_Raja  Ok Rambo. Don't forget your name is Rambo as you are GOING TO CODE A LOT...(joking). The only solution I see is that you pivot  your columns yourself. Prior to 11g, people used to do it. Start a bounty on your question or read read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643731/oracle10g-sql-turning-columns-into-rows  or this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512140/convert-row-into-columns-in-oracle10g